# Detecting insufficient PHP variables: FALSE vs NULL vs unset() vs empty()?

Tags: php

What is the best way to define that a value does not exist in PHP, or is not sufficent for the applications needs.

`$var = NULL`, `$var = array()`, `$var = FALSE`?

And what is the best way to test?

`isset($var)`, `empty($var)`, `if($var != NULL)`, `if($var)`?

Initializing variables as what they will be, e.g. `NULL` if a string, `array()` if they will be arrays, has some benefits in that they will function in the setting they are ment to without any unexpected results.

e.g. `foreach($emptyArray)` won't complain it just wont output anything, whereas `foreach($false)` will complain about the wrong variable type.

But it seams like an unnecessary hassle to have so many different ways of doing basically the same thing. eg. `if(empty($var))` or `if ($var == NULL)`

---

**Duplicate:** [Best way to test for a variable’s existence in PHP; isset() is clearly broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418066)

Comment: I disagree, that post has no mention of empty() or using FALSE, and has no mention of the merits of initializing a variable according to it's intended use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each function you named is for different purposes, and they should be used accordingly:

- **[empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)**: tells if an existing variable is with a value that could be considered empty (0 for numbers, empty array for arrays, equal to NULL, etc.).
- **[isset($var)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**: tells if the script encountered a line before where the variable was the left side of an assignment (i.e. $var = 3;) or any other obscure methods such as [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) or [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). This is *the* way to find if a variable has been set.
- **[$var == NULL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)**: This is tricky, since 0 == NULL. If you really want to tell if a variable is NULL, you should use triple =: $var === NULL.
- **[if($var)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)**: same as $var == NULL.

As useful link is https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.

The way to tell if the variable is good for a piece of script you're coding will entirely depend on your code, so there's no single way of checking it.

One last piece of advice: if you expect a variable to be an array, don't wait for it to be set somewhere. Instead, initialize it beforehand, then let your code run and maybe it will get overwritten with a new array:

```
// Initialize the variable, so we always get an array in this variable without worrying about other code.
$var = array();

if(some_weird_condition){
  $var = array(1, 2, 3);
}

// Will work every time.
foreach($var as $key => $value){
}
```

Comment: some minor corrections: empty() will also return true whenever a variable is FALSE (not only empty strings or empty arrays); isset() doesn't exactly look for a variable assignment, as a variable can be set in other ways (extract, etc); if($var) returns true when $var is neither NULL, FALSE or 0...

Comment: Thanks! Added part of your text to the answer. BTW, if($var) I said it was the same as $var == NULL, which ends up TRUE in the cases you listed (NULL, FALSE and 0).

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to remember is that since php is liberal in what it allows to evaluate to NULL or empty, it's necessary to use the identity operators (===, !== see [http://php.net/operators.comparison](http://ca.php.net/operators.comparison). This is the reason why all of these comparison and equality functions exists, since you often have to differentiate between values with subtle differences.

If you are explicitly checking for NULL, always use $var === NULL

Answer (score -1):

My vote goes for unset(), because non existing variables should generate an notice when used.

Testing gets a bit more complicated, because isset() wil be false if the variable is "not existings" or null. (Language designflaw if you'd ask me)

You could use array_key_exists() for valiables in $GLOBALS, $_POST etc.
For class properties there is property_exists().