# Check if value isset and null

Tags: php, null, isset

I need to check if value is defined as anything, including null. `isset` treats null values as undefined and returns `false`. Take the following as an example:

```
$foo = null;

if(isset($foo)) // returns false
if(isset($bar)) // returns false
if(isset($foo) || is_null($foo)) // returns true
if(isset($bar) || is_null($bar)) // returns true, raises a notice
```

Note that `$bar` is undefined.

I need to find a condition that satisfies the following:

```
if(something($bar)) // returns false;
if(something($foo)) // returns true;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if(isset($foo)) // returns false, i fell off the chair, all these years...

Comment: in_array($key,array_keys($_SESSION)) && is_null($_SESSION[$key])
I was wondering this for so long ..

Comment: This is not a normal behave for me, `isset` = is set ?, your variable is set at null. I wasted lot of time because of this one...

Comment: @VincentDecaux it's PHP... Just an example of many more illogical things in the language...

Answer (score 100, accepted):

IIRC, you can use [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) for this:

```
$foo = NULL;
$vars = get_defined_vars();
if (array_key_exists('bar', $vars)) {}; // Should evaluate to FALSE
if (array_key_exists('foo', $vars)) {}; // Should evaluate to TRUE
```

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest the same function, `get_defined_vars` happily copes with scope.

Comment: Seems to be working, but I was hoping for something simpler. Oh well. Let's see if anyone can come up with a one liner.

Comment: well, you don't need vars, so in theory its one line "if(array_key_exists('foo',get_defined_vars())){} "

Comment: [fvn's newer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39721756/199364) might be a quicker way to get a variable that exists in current context, *avoiding the cost* of `get_defined_vars()`:  `array_key_exists('foo', compact('foo'))`. Or faster, if testing a global: `array_key_exists('foo', $GLOBALS)`.

Answer (score 34):

If you are dealing with object properties which might have a value of NULL you can use: [`property_exists()`](https://www.php.net/property_exists) instead of `isset()`

```
<?php

class myClass {
    public $mine;
    private $xpto;
    static protected $test;

    function test() {
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'xpto')); //true
    }
}

var_dump(property_exists('myClass', 'mine'));   //true
var_dump(property_exists(new myClass, 'mine')); //true
var_dump(property_exists('myClass', 'xpto'));   //true, as of PHP 5.3.0
var_dump(property_exists('myClass', 'bar'));    //false
var_dump(property_exists('myClass', 'test'));   //true, as of PHP 5.3.0
myClass::test();

?>
```

> As opposed with isset(), property_exists() returns TRUE even if the property has the value NULL.

Comment: You can do the same for arrays with array_key_exists();

Comment: Yes, but it is NOT possible to use this one to see if a declared property has yet been initialised. For this you can use isset(), but then of course you have a problem with readonly properties if they have been initialised to null. I've seen people grabbing to Refelction in those cases, another solution is Try/Catch but it shouldn't be that complicated!

Comment: Plus the fact that dynamic properties are deprecated nowadays make this method (after 9 years of being useful) not recommended.

Answer (score 17):

See [Best way to test for a variable's existence in PHP; isset() is clearly broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418066/best-way-to-test-for-a-variables-existence-in-php-isset-is-clearly-broken)

```
 if( array_key_exists('foo', $GLOBALS) && is_null($foo)) // true & true => true
 if( array_key_exists('bar', $GLOBALS) && is_null($bar)) // false &  => false
```

Comment: The code you quote only works if the variable is in the global scope.

Comment: Indeed but isn't it the most frequent case ? In a function you will have variables at global scope and arguments (which are always defined). You could also have object properties but then you can use 'property_exists'.

Comment: Using $GLOBALS seems a bit volatile, I have to do some testing myself before I can declare this as working.

Comment: Just a note 13 years later: do not use global variables. We've moved on, it never was a good idea to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

I found this topic when I was looking for a solution for an array. to check for the presence of an array element that contains NULL, this construction helped me

```
    $arr= [];
    $foo = 'foo';
    $arr[$foo]= NULL;
    if (array_key_exists('bar', $arr)) {}; // Should evaluate to FALSE
    if (array_key_exists('foo', $arr)) {}; // Should evaluate to TRUE
    if (array_key_exists($foo, $arr)) {}; // Should evaluate to TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found that `compact` is a function that ignores unset variables but does act on ones set to `null`, so when you have a large local symbol table I would imagine you can get a more efficient solution over checking  `array_key_exists('foo', get_defined_vars())` by using `array_key_exists('foo', compact('foo'))`:

```
$foo = null;
echo isset($foo) ? 'true' : 'false'; // false
echo array_key_exists('foo', compact('foo')) ? 'true' : 'false'; // true
echo isset($bar) ? 'true' : 'false'; // false
echo array_key_exists('bar', compact('bar')) ? 'true' : 'false'; // false
```

**Update**

As of PHP 7.3 [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) will give a notice for unset values, so unfortunately this alternative is no longer valid.

> compact() now issues an E_NOTICE level error if a given string refers to an unset variable. Formerly, such strings have been silently
>   skipped.

Comment: Interesting alternative. But note that it is probably *slower* than calling array_key_exists on an existing array, such as $GLOBALS - because a look up in a hash table does not get any slower, when the table gets large, and you've added the extra work of `compact`. Nevertheless, I upvoted it because it is useful in one situation: if you want to know whether `foo` exists *in the current context*, regardless of where it came from - if you don't care whether is local or global, just want to know whether it exists.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I was actually referring to the potentially significant overhead of calling `get_defined_vars`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808704/what-is-the-performance-impact-off-get-defined-vars).

Answer (score 1):

The following code written as PHP extension is equivalent to array_key_exists($name, get_defined_vars()) (thanks to Henrik and Hannes).

```
// get_defined_vars()
// https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L1777
// array_key_exists
// https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L4393

PHP_FUNCTION(is_defined_var)
{

    char *name;
    int name_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &name, &name_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (!EG(active_symbol_table)) {
        zend_rebuild_symbol_table(TSRMLS_C);
    }

    if (zend_symtable_exists(EG(active_symbol_table), name, name_len + 1)) {
        RETURN_TRUE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some silly workaround using xdebug. ;-)

```
function is_declared($name) {
    ob_start();
    xdebug_debug_zval($name);
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return !empty($content);
}

$foo = null;
var_dump(is_declared('foo')); // -> true

$bla = 'bla';
var_dump(is_declared('bla')); // -> true

var_dump(is_declared('bar')); // -> false
```

Comment: Doesn't look very portable.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the following code:

```php
class SomeClass {

  private $cachedInstance;

  public instance()
  {
    if (! isset($this->cachedInstance)) {
      $this->cachedInstance = GetCachedInstanceFromDb(); // long operation, that could return Null if the record not found
    }

    return $this->cachedInstance;
  }
}
```

And it failed in a way that `GetCachedInstanceFromDb()` got called multiple times if it returned null. All because `isset()` would return false even if the property was explicitly set to Null.

So, I had to do the following changes:

1. Declare the property with initial value set to False;
2. Use strict (type-safe) comparison when checking for the current variable value;

```php
class SomeClass {

  private $cachedInstance = false; // #1

  public instance()
  {
    if ($this->cachedInstance === false) { // #2
      $this->cachedInstance = GetCachedInstanceFromDb();
    }

    return $this->cachedInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: if you use typed parameters, then you cannot use this solution

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev with union types I can )) Just wondering if it's possible to typehint something as `ObjectName|false`, instead of `ObjectName|bool`

Comment: > Just wondering if it's possible to typehint something as `ObjectName|false`, instead of `ObjectName|bool` -- And I can! It would even throw a type error if I try to assign that property a `true`! At least in PHP 8.3. Though, for this example it should be: `protected ObjectName|**null**|false $propName = false;`

Answer (score -1):

You could use [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) and [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of isset(). Empty doesn't print an error message if the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: I am using is_null. The result is same regardless of the `isset`.

Comment: I made a mistake while posting my first answer : did you try with empty() ?

Comment: This won't work for values that are not empty and not NULL such as FALSE, 0, array() or "".

Comment: This answer is wrong. `is_null` has the same problem as `is_set`: it can't distinguish between "not set" and "set to null", which is the problem OP has. `empty` is even worse, as Calum points out.

Answer (score -1):

At risk of being downvoted, I wouldn't even bother - clearly PHP wanted you to logically think of NULL and Undef as the same.  I just ran with it - I created a function:

```
bool isEmpty(& $davar);
```

that checks for isset (handles both null and undef), "", and array().  Note that this is purposefully not dealing with falseness; just empty.  The & 'reference-izer' allows the variable to be passed even though undefined without an error message, and if you check for isset and return false first, your next checks against "" and array() can be made without error.

The next function takes advantage of this function and is used where you would use

```
$davar || some-default.
```

and that is:

```
mixed defaultForEmpty(& $daVar, $default);
```

which just has the condition:

```
if (isEmpty($daVar)) 
    return $default;
else
    return $daVar;
```

BTW, these work with object references, array indexes, $_GET, $_POST, etc..

Answer (score -3):

`is_null($bar)` returns true, since it has no values at all. Alternatively, you can use:

```
if(isset($bar) && is_null($bar)) // returns false
```

to check if `$bar` is defined and will only return true if:

```
$bar = null;
if(isset($bar) && is_null($bar)) // returns true
```

Comment: No, he said that `if(isset($bar))` gives false when `$bar = null`.

Comment: This will not pass any other variables than null (eg. if `$bar = "test"`).

Comment: When $bar = null isset() will return "false" and is_null() will return  true. False and true gives always false.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. As OP said, `isset($bar)` returns false, even after `$bar = null;`.