# PHP null var exists

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if value isset and null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803282/check-if-value-isset-and-null)

If I have `$v = NULL;` how can I check  that `$v` is exists and it's `NULL`?

```
isset($v) => false //because of NULL, but $v exists
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t, [`null`](http://php.net/language.types.null) is equivalent to a non-existing variable:

> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant `NULL`.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been `unset()`.

Only for arrays you can check whether a key exists although its value is `null` using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists).

Comment: +1 This answer is more correct than the others because it addresses both parts of the question ($v exists AND is null).

Comment: Erm, what's about using `array_key_exists` with `$GLOBALS`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: @kirilloid That would work – but only with [global variables](http://php.net/language.variables.scope).

Comment: I know, this is similar to JS. You cannot access global variable by its name with `window[name]`, but it's impossbile for variables in current scope.

Comment: -1 You CAN. Based on my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803282/check-if-value-isset-and-null#answer-39721756), to check that $v exists and it's NULL you would do: `array_key_exists('v', compact('v')) && is_null($v);`

Answer (score 0):

Try `is_null($v)`.

[The PHP online docs are friendly!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

Comment: if $v is not exists it'll return warning.

Comment: @Yekver you'll need to combine both.

Comment: @Xeon06 How would you do that? As far as `isset()` and `is_null()` are concerned, the two are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Null ah you're right, I didn't think this through.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful using `isset` on variables that can be `null`. It's a good way to set yourself up for bugs and problems in the future.

What you could do for now is to use [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) as an additional test.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to put it all together to test existence and a null value

```
<?php
if(!is_null($v)){
// do something
}
?>
```