# PHP: check if posted variable exists or assign null value

Tags: php, conditional-operator

This can be done in Javascript with isNAN instead of !isset.
Using the example below - both forms post to my script, one without a value and one with a value. Is the below code a correct way to do this in PHP to assign a value if the post var is not present?

**$mycheck = !isset($_POST['value']) ? 0 : $_POST['value'];**

```
<? 
if($_POST) :
  $mycheck = !isset($_POST['value']) ? 0 : $_POST['value'];
  echo $mycheck;
endif;
?>

<!-- send value-->
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="value">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<!-- doesn't send value-->
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="different_var">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3803347/632951

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's an acceptable way of setting default values.

An alternative, introduced in PHP 5.3, is to omit the middle argument of your ternary expression:

```
$mycheck = $_POST['value'] ?: 0;
```

However, this will likely throw notices for trying to access an array with a non-existant key if `$_POST['value']` isn't set. Therefore your original method is more-accepted.

Comment: It should be `$_POST['value']` instead of `isset($_POST['value'])`, as per the OP's intentions.

Comment: I think that `isset()` is perfectly acceptable for this solution.  It will always give true or false, and will do exactly what the OP wants...

Comment: so if the posted value is a string your method is acceptable, but if its an array its better to use my original method?

Comment: I would think so.  Ternary operators are looking for a true/false response and `isset()` will always give you that, even with an array.

Comment: @Innate Sort of but not quite. It depends on whether the value is already defined (hence, if you had an undefined string `$value`, the abbreviated notation will still throw notices). However, notices are rarely ever worth paying attention to and almost certainly not worth writing longer code to avoid; a case of useless notices is where `session_start()` will throw notices at you if a session is already declared, even though you need `session_start()` on every page to extend the session.

Comment: Take a look at F. Orvalho's answer though, he brings up a valid point.

Comment: something to note here is that the posted value is a numeric value. this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use make me wonder if !empty() is the better way to go - re F. Orvalho's answer. empty throws an error however - undefined index.

Answer (score 1):

It works, but there's a cleaner way of writing it.

As of PHP 5.3, you can shorten ternary operations down to two expressions, like so:

```
$mycheck = $_POST['value'] ?: 0;
```

It means basically what you already have.