# What is the performance impact off `get_defined_vars()`?

Tags: php, performance, memory

Every so often I see questions on SO whose answers/solutions include the use of `get_defined_vars()`, or blog posts on the internet that use the method.  In most instances it is used for debugging purposes, but in some instances it seems as though the authors have the intention to use it in production code.

While I rarely use the function because it makes me feel off inside, I was wondering what the actual performance impact of using this function was in a PHP application.

One [example](http://ideone.com/3hyrYX) of it's usage may be to see if a variable is explicitly set to `NULL`:

```
//$implicit_null = 1234;
$explicit_null = NULL;

var_dump(is_null($implicit_null)); // TRUE, also throws undefined index error
var_dump((
    array_key_exists('implicit_null',get_defined_vars()) && 
    is_null($implicit_null)
)); // FALSE
```

There are other use-cases circulating on the internet, but very little outlining what the performance or memory impacts may be.

Comment: @PaulCrovella - I have a way, and have, which is why I pressed the "answer your own question" button.  I asked the question exclusively so I could answer it.  That said, I would also be interested in other's findings or corrections.

Comment: That is fair, and I have a fairly standard means of measuring the performance of chunks of code, but before I go and run those tests myself, I will often Google, to see if it is even worth it.  First.  That said, there are also a slew of SO questions/answers regarding this, so it helps to have a solid SO answer about it's performance to reference in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the memory impact can vary, but in worst-case, it can nearly [double your memory usage](http://ideone.com/tqjvgV).

```
function report_memory($string = '') {
    $mem = (memory_get_usage()/1000);
    echo "$string: {$mem}kb\n";
    return $mem;
}

// ~117.164kb
$start = report_memory('Start of stript');

for($i = 10000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $var = "filler_$i";
    $$var = 'banana';
}

// ~1022.752kb after fill
$fill_size = ($after_fill = report_memory('After banana')) - $start;
// ~905.588kb fill size
echo "Fill Size: {$fill_size}kb\n\n";

$tmp_vars = get_defined_vars();

// ~1649.12kb after function call
$grew = report_memory('After get_defined_vars()') - $after_fill;
// ~626.368kb growth due to call
echo "Growth from get_defined_vars(): {$grew}kb\n\n";
```

Again, this is worst-case.  I did see [some odd behavior](http://ideone.com/hQzfDj) when simply filling an array with `array_fill()`.  As you can see here, the growth from calling `get_defined_vars()` is VERY small, compared to creating variables themselves.  I thought, at first, that this was due to `array`s being returned as references, but this is [clearly not the case](http://ideone.com/pP1eLN). It should also be noted, however, that objects WILL be [returned as references](http://ideone.com/6MYkIe), as objects always are.

All of that said, it is unlikely that all of your global variables are going to be arrays upon arrays upon arrays, and all of those strings, binary data, and numbers are going to add up fairly quickly.

In the end, this is a single function that can nearly double your memory footprint, and incurs a [significant wall-time](http://ideone.com/kJgORw):

```
for($i = 10000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $var = "filler_$i";
    $$var = 'banana';
}

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 250; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $all = get_defined_vars();
}

$stop = microtime(TRUE);
echo round(((($stop - $start))/250)*1000000, 2); // ~1967.45 microseconds
```

**General conclusion**

Use **only** for debugging, I wouldn't even get in the habit of leaving it in the code over night.  Use sparingly.