# Why should I fix E_NOTICE errors?

Tags: php

As a developer, I work with E_NOTICE turned on. Recently though, I was asked why E_NOTICE errors should be fixed. The only reason that I could come up with was that it is best practice to correct those problems.

Does anyone else have any reasons to justify the extra time/cost spent to correct these problems?

More specifically, why should a manager spend the money to have these fixed if the code already works?

Comment: I have absolutely no data to support this, but I would imagine PHP triggering notices is a bit of a performance hit, even if those notices aren't printed to the screen.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc yes, but negligible. I don't think he is asking about performance, but more why it is a best practice to address E_NOTICE errors.

Comment: The best way to learn why you should fix E_NOTICE errors is to disable them for a while. They'll bite you in a way that you'll have plenty of cursing data to back you up! ;)

Comment: May I ask how do you "fix" notices? Do you classify them unilaterally as errors, or can you discern debug messages?

Comment: @mario - use something like the PHP Debug toolbar. Check out some [sample output](http://www.php-debug.com/www/PHP_Debug_HTML_Table_test.php).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**SUMMARY**

The [PHP Runtime Configuration Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) give you some idea why:

> Enabling E_NOTICE during development has some benefits.
>
> For debugging purposes: NOTICE messages will warn you about possible bugs in your code. For example, use of unassigned values is warned. It is extremely useful to find typos and to save time for debugging.
>
> NOTICE messages will warn you about bad style. For example, $arr[item] is better to be written as $arr['item'] since PHP tries to treat "item" as constant. If it is not a constant, PHP assumes it is a string index for the array.

Here's a more detailed explanation of each...

---

**1. TO DETECT TYPOS**

The main cause of `E_NOTICE` errors is typos.

**Example - notice.php**

```
<?php
$username = 'joe';        // in real life this would be from $_SESSION

// and then much further down in the code...

if ($usernmae) {            // typo, $usernmae expands to null
    echo "Logged in";
}
else {
    echo "Please log in...";
}
?>
```

**Output without E_NOTICE**

```
Please log in...
```

Wrong!  You didn't mean that!

**Output with E_NOTICE**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: usernmae in /home/user/notice.php on line 3
Please log in...
```

In PHP, a variable that doesn't exist will return null rather than causing an error, and that could cause code to behave differently than expected, so it's best to heed `E_NOTICE` warnings.

---

**2. TO DETECT AMBIGUOUS ARRAY INDEXES**

It also warns you about array indexes that might change on you, e.g.

**Example - code looks like this today**

```
<?php

$arr = array();
$arr['username'] = 'fred';

// then further down

echo $arr[username];
?>
```

**Output without E_NOTICE**

```
fred
```

**Example - tomorrow you include a library**

```
<?php
// tomorrow someone adds this
include_once('somelib.php');

$arr = array();
$arr['username'] = 'fred';

// then further down

echo $arr[username];
?>
```

**and the library does something like this:**

```
<?php
define("username", "Mary");
?>
```

**New output**

Empty, because now it expands to:

```
echo $arr["Mary"];
```

and there is no key `Mary` in `$arr`.

**Output with E_NOTICE**

If only the programmer had `E_NOTICE` on, PHP would have printed an error message:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in /home/user/example2.php on line 8
fred
```

---

**3. THE BEST REASON**

If you don't fix all the `E_NOTICE` errors that you think aren't errors, you will probably grow complacent, and start ignoring the messages, and then one day when a real error happens, you won't notice it.

Comment: even if i think that my notices isn't an errors and i have enabled E_NOTICES on my live server, and i can't disable them, what should i do? is there any practices or code styles to omit every notice and warning?

Comment: See [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for a start.

Comment: So you want to hide "every notice and warning" but you're not allowed to turn them off?  You could try sending the output to [`syslog`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) and have separate files for notice and warning, so you can ignore them unless something is broken.  Or try [log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/).

Comment: This answer clearly explains what many developers don't understand: that notices are a *tool*, just like HTML validators, source control or unit testing (or error messages in general).

Answer (score 15):

Because an `E_NOTICE` indicates an **error**.
PHP is just too forgiving to call it that.

For example, accessing an undefined variable produces an `E_NOTICE`.
If this happens often, for example because you're not initializing your variables correctly, and your app is throwing notices all over the place, **how are you going to tell the difference between a "variable that works just fine uninitialized" and times when you have really fat-fingered a variable name?**

This may trigger a notice but will work as intended, so you ignore the notice:

```
if ($_GET['foo']) ...
```

This, on the other hand, will waste half your day while you ignore the notice and are trying to figure out why your "`bar()` function doesn't work":

```
$foo = bar();
if ($too) ...
```

If you don't "fix" the former case, where the variable may legitimately not exist, you can't meaningfully use notices to catch the typo in the second case.

Notices are there to help you debug your app. If you ignore them, you're only making your own life more difficult.

Comment: Would a motoric isset user ever get a notice for the second case?

Comment: @mario Good question. Wasn't a perfect example. Think of the variable as being always expected to exist there. ;) See @Mikel's answer for more consistent example.

Comment: if ($_GET['foo']) ... is still triggering notice. if i have E_NOTICEs enabled on my live server what coding style should i use to omit EVERY notice and warning in my code?

Comment: @llamerr You can suppress the display of notices with `ini_set('display_errors', false)`. Of course that's not what you should do, if you read my answer.

Comment: I agree with the "forgiving" aspect. Accessing an undefined variable in most languages produces problems from crashes to security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of errors are good practice to fix, as they are what we call "code smell" they hint of another problem (like mistyped variable names or usage of undefined variables/wrong usage of methods) , or they will probably cause bugs down the road when you reflector/expand the system.
Of course, what I said here is not true 100% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Ben I think this is an excellent question. True, it is a good practice to follow to attempt to correct any and all errors, even non-fatal ones, unless doing to would impede the designed (and thus desired) functionality of the system. Moreover, **any** level of error indicates that either:

a) There is something wrong with your code, or,
b) You have written code that is deprecated, or have written code that is otherwise unstable and thus prone to side effects.

Therefore, I believe that if the timeline and budget of a project allows you to do so, you should always strive to correct as many errors as possible, even if they are minor in terms of their impact on the final product.

Of course, there is a certain level of risk acceptance involved in cost-benefit analysis, so it may very well be the case that the managers overseeing the outcome of the project are willing to hedge the potential future cost of fixing a known issue against the present time and cost savings associate with *not* fixing an error. The math basically works out the way you think it would: If the PV of the cost of fixing the error in the future is less than the money saved today by not fixing the error, then you should not fix it. On the other hand, if the PV of the cost of fixing the error in the future is greater than the money saved today by not fixing it, then you should fix it today.

That, really, is the justification for (or against) fixing an error today, regardless of the error level.

Answer (score 1):

Often they're indicative of logic errors or typos. They'll help you spot situations where you've mistyped a variable name or are trying to use a variable before it's been set.

I've also seen arguments that [it's more efficient to avoid errors](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance)