# How to check whether a post was made or not?

Tags: php, post, xdebug, easyphp

```
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
{
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]); /* Line 10 */
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

if (!$result)
    {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['password'] == $password)
    {
        ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","360000");
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        mysql_close($link);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }


mysql_close($link);
}
```

I'm not making any posts but it says that `$email` is not defined at line 10. Why? I use [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/).

> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\v0.3\model\login.php
>   on line 10

Comment: Is the code snippet you posted located on lines 9 and 10 of the file login.php? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: @deceze, sorry, code updated.

Comment: Are you sure this is copy-pasted 100% correctly? There are no weird unicode characters or other invisibles in there? If everything is typed correctly this should not happen...

Comment: Hey ilhan, you should read this article about storing passwords safely: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most reliable method for checking if a POST was done is via

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... you're in a post ...
}
```

Checking for a particular form field is risky - you might rename/delete the field and forget to update the form. But checking for that $_SERVER value is 100% reliable - it's always available, regardless of what method the script was invoked via.

Answer (score 0):

It says that because the `$_POST` array is empty (of course, you are not posting) and you are trying to access the `email` index of that array `if(isset($_POST["email"]))`, which doesn't exist.

You could fix this by doing:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']))
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
```

**Note**: that this is only a notice, and it won't affect your application, so i would suggest you don't worry too much about it and you will have a cleaner code. **This is a personal opinion** check out why you should not here: [How to avoid isset() and empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly/)

**UPDATE**

Added isset function to prevent notice. Thanks to deceze.

Comment: This ain't Javascript, *this* will certainly throw a notice if `email` isn't set. `isset` is the correct thing to use! And you **must** worry about notices. -1

Comment: the notices won't effect my application but the visitor has to scroll down several pages

Comment: @deceze i worry about getting my answer right, not about other users answers, regardingthe notices, i have several years ignoring them, never had a problem but i guess that is just a personal opinion

Comment: @ilhan if you show notices and errors in production code that is considered a security breach, you should only show errors during development

Comment: Please see [Why should I fix E_NOTICE errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073642/why-should-i-fix-e-notice-errors) and [isset() and empty() make code ugly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly/).

Comment: that was quite an answer, i will read more on this (added the link my post here).

Comment: Thank yo deceze, error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE in php.ini solved my problem.

Comment: @ilhan Noooooooo~! You're taking my advise completely backwards!  ( > < ；)//

Answer (score 0):

`array() == false`, so why not:

```
if($_POST)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Some people won't like this, but I say if you're using a dynamic language, you might as well take advantage of it.

Comment: [Click here to see an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post#answer-409417) that helps clarify the exact difference in function between  
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {...}`  
and  
`if($_POST){...}`