# Why would a person want to use isset over just !$variableName

Tags: php, isset

I was wondering why would someone want to use the function `isset` over just the `!` to say a variable isn't set or existant.

For example:

```
<?php
    if(!$name){
        echo 'Name is not set';
    }
    if(isset($name) == false){
        echo 'Returned false';
    }
?>
```

Wouldn't they both be echoed out? I've been told that using `isset` is better but I fail to see why. Can someone explain?

Comment: Because otherwise error reporting is useless → duplicate of [Why should I fix E\_NOTICE errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073642/why-should-i-fix-e-notice-errors), [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: You want to use `(!$variableName)` but you still use `(isset($name) == false)`? :D `(!isset($name))` will save your time, because it only returns boolean values.

Comment: I wasn't asking about any errors, I was asking about why one is better than the other. So not a duplicate. And thank you Jari, I knew you could do that but kind of spaced out when writing this.

Comment: The reason *is* errors. The question is phrased differently, yes, but the core issue is errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we use directly $variableName and the $variableName is not defined before that check, then a **Undefined variable** warning will be generated by php. If we use isset, then if the variable is defined before, then it is set the isset will return true, if not defined then isset will return false, and hence no **Undefined Variable or index** warning will be generated.

It is a good practice to use isset with variables if there is a case that it is not defined before.

```
<?php
    if(!$name){   //this will generate a warning
        echo 'Name is not set';
    }
    if(isset($name) == false){   //this will not as isset returns false
        echo 'Returned false';
    }
?>
```

Comment: The operator `!` in PHP use as `NOT` function and not to use to check if variable is set! Your answer is "what will happens" if he use it like this, you not explained why this happened.

Comment: Yes, ! is logical NOT operator, and it convert TRUE to FALSE. Here 1 is true, 2 is also and "you are a genius" is also true. On whatever data use use ! , if it is not null and defined before using !, it will work fine. But if the variable or data is not defined, it will still work but php will generate a warning also.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable does not exist and you're trying to access it, this will generate a warning:

```
if ($foo) ... // E_NOTICE: Undefined variable foo
```

The value of this non-existent variable is `null` so the result is the same, meaning that the `if` condition will not be satisfied and the code will not execute, but you get this warning notifying you of a potential problem (which it is).

You use `isset` to test whether a variable exist without triggering an error. You should only use this for variables which you really cannot be sure about. If a variable *should* be set at some point in your code, you do not need `isset`; you want a warning notice instead if a variable doesn't exist when it should.

Answer (score 1):

### Not defined values

If `$name` is not defined the first `if` will output a warning and return `false`. 
( `E_NOTICE` )

The second `if` will function normally and will return `false`.

### Boolean values

If `$name` is `true` only the second `if` will output the `echo`.

```
if(!$name){
    echo 'Name is not set';
}

if(isset($name) == false){
    echo 'Returned false';
}
```

Thus, `isset` is more coherent with what you want to retrieve from this conditional. You only want to see if `$name` has a value defined or not.

### Integer values

if `$name`is `0` the first `if` will output that name is not set, but the second if will return `true`, because the variable `$name` is set. Thus more coherency.

### Conclusion

`isset` is better because it does exactly what you want to retrieve and what you want.

Answer (score -1):

The `isset()` function Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

If a variable has been unset with `unset()`, it will no longer be set. `isset()` will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. Also note that a NULL byte `("\0")` is not equivalent to the PHP NULL constant.

If multiple parameters are supplied then `isset()` will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

if you not using `isset()` the script will generated a warning, with `isset()` you can prevents this.

a for example reason to use `isset()` is to detect if key is inside array.

for example:

```
<?php

$a = array ('test' => 1, 'hello' => NULL, 'pie' => array('a' => 'apple'));

var_dump(isset($a['test']));            // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['foo']));             // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['hello']));           // FALSE

// The key 'hello' equals NULL so is considered unset
// If you want to check for NULL key values then try: 
var_dump(array_key_exists('hello', $a)); // TRUE

// Checking deeper array values
var_dump(isset($a['pie']['a']));        // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['pie']['b']));        // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['cake']['a']['b']));  // FALSE

 if(!$a['hello']){   //this will display a warning: Undefined variable.
    echo 'hello is not set in the array';
}
?>
```

The problem with your example is the operator `!` in PHP is `NOT`, So in the two if line's here you will get the same result but the first line will display **Undefined** variable warning because there is no `$name` variable, the second if will do `NOT` to `$name` variable

```
<?php
    if(!$name){//this will display a warning: Undefined variable.
        echo 'Name is not set';
    }

     $name=0;
     if(!$name){//check the not value of $name.
        echo 'Name is true';
    }

?>
```