# How to know if a PHP variable exists, even if its value is NULL?

Tags: php, null, isset

```
$a = NULL;
$c = 1;
var_dump(isset($a)); // bool(false)
var_dump(isset($b)); // bool(false)
var_dump(isset($c)); // bool(true)
```

How can I distinguish `$a`, which exists but has a value of `NULL`, from the  “really non-existent” `$b`?

Comment: Why? Just initialize your variables properly and you _know_ which one exists and which doesn't

Comment: I wouldn't even use isset. Initialize your variables so you can assume they exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418066/best-way-to-test-for-a-variables-existence-in-php-isset-is-clearly-broken

Comment: @KingCrunch: Theorical question or specific edge case, either ways the question was not about if it's appropriate or not. Please stay constructive.

Comment: @Insterstellar_Coder: Thanks, I had not found that topic :) ( Even if I don't really like the _GLOBAL solution )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$a = NULL;
var_dump(true === array_key_exists('a', get_defined_vars()));
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be interesting to know why you want to do this, but in any event, it is possible:

Use [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/%20get_defined_vars), which will contain an entry for defined variables in the current scope, including those with NULL values. Here's an example of its use

```
function test()
{
    $a=1;
    $b=null;

    //what is defined in the current scope?
    $defined= get_defined_vars();

    //take a look...
    var_dump($defined);

    //here's how you could test for $b
    $is_b_defined = array_key_exists('b', $defined);
}

test();
```

This displays

```
array(2) {
  ["a"] => int(1)
  ["b"] => NULL
}
```