# PHP login trouble

Tags: php, undefined-index

Having some trouble with a PHP login that I found online -

```
 <?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="SOME_USERNAME"; // Mysql username 
$password="SOME_PASSWORD"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="b00556019"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
  if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
 }
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
 ?>
```

The error is on lines 16-17 and shows as follow -

```
Notice: Undefined index: myusername in E:\home\students\2137\B00556019\public_html\workspace\login\checklogin.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: mypassword in E:\home\students\2137\B00556019\public_html\workspace\login\checklogin.php on line 17
```

Wrong Username or Password

this is the 2 lines not working :

```
 $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
 $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>#
```

Anybody with any ideas or a better tutorial example would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you should use for password fields in forms `type="password"`

Comment: use isset to check if the indexes are there. and once you do it, delete your code and don't look back

Comment: You have a `</form>` tag but you forgot the `<form>`

Comment: This code is obsolete. `Mysql_*` and `session_register()` are deprecated. You should *not* be using them. `strip_slashes()` should only be necessary of magic quotes is enabled which is also obsolete. **You should not be using this code**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to test for a variable's existence in PHP; isset() is clearly broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418066/best-way-to-test-for-a-variables-existence-in-php-isset-is-clearly-broken)

Comment: Not sure but `session_register()` is outdated, just use `$_SESSION[]`.

Comment: Add [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start) and change `session_register("myusername"); session_register("mypassword");` to `$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername; $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;` - [`session_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[]` contains data from form submissions from HTML. If an user didn't have send in a form, the `$myusername` field will be empty because the index (actually the key) `'myusername'` cannot be found in the array. That's why you are getting these errors.

```
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

to ensure that the POST data (from form submissions) contains the keys/indexes, please use `isset()` command, (or [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), both works.)

```
if(isset($_POST['myusername']) && isset($_POST['mypassword']) {
    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword"); 
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    } 
}
```

But if you want to use the `$_POST`, you have to write a form in your HTML. Also i recommend to not use table for aligning the HTML form elements. It's not an elegant solution. There are many examples on stackoverflow of how-to.

Here below is an example of your form in HTML5

```
<form action="#" method="post">
     <label for="myusername">Your username : </label>
     <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" />
     <label for="mypassword">Your password : </label>
     <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword" />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

the [`<label for="input id">`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) hooks a label text to the input box. If an user clicks on the text, the `for` attribute ensures the browser that the focus will be at the input element where the `for` is pointing to.

Then the [`<input>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) has many attributes. The `name` field is used for serverside programs to handle the form submissions. The `id` for the browser itself. It is mainly used by CSS and client side scripts.

Also, you are using a very outdated tutorial to achieve a login webpage. `mysql()` functions are officially deprecated. Please use [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Also, [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) should guide you in the PDO world without problems

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
if(isset($_POST['myusername']) && $_POST['myusername']!=''){
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
   $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
   $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
   $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
   $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and     password='$mypassword'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
 if($count==1){

 // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
   session_register("myusername");
   session_register("mypassword"); 
  header("location:login_success.php");
 }
else {
 echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}


}
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add form start tag and it will start working

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"               bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td> 
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
```

specify action as per your requirement