# PHP - variables already set but return false with isset?

Tags: php, variables, isset

Very basic question in PHP - I have set a variable to null, why do I get false in the result?

```
$a = null;
var_dump(isset($a)); // false
```

How do I just check if a variable **is set** if `isset` is not the one I am after?

I can't use `empty`, for example,

```
var_dump(empty($b)); // false
```

But `$b` is not set at all.

I can do that in javascript which makes more sense,

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') ...
```

Comment: null is not really an assignment. Check it out : https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: @Random `null` is a perfectly fine assignment.

Comment: @deceze it is not really as it does the same thing as `var $a`, php can't make the difference, so it is more a declaration than an assignment...

Comment: @Random A variable which exists and holds the value `null` is a perfectly fine variable. When trying to access a non-existent variable, its value will be substituted by `null` and a warning is raised. They're both different though. The default value for a `public $a` in a class also happens to be `null`. Just `$a;` outside a class actually **does nothing at all**, it does not even create the variable, it's a complete NOOP. Still not the same as `$a = null`. – But yes, incidentally it's impossible to distinguish a non-existent variable and a variable holding `null`.

Comment: @deceze yeah but having an attribute `public $a`, using `$this->a = null` makes nothing... $a is already "declared".

Comment: @Random Well, that assigns `null` to `$this->a` which already happened to contain the value `null` anyway. It *does* something, but nothing much is changing.

Comment: @teelou You shouldn't really ever need to check for the existence of variables that much anyway. Initialise your variables properly and keep your fingers off of `isset` most of the time. See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: @deceze so I can't check it at all in PHP? what about in other languages?

Comment: Let's keep this discussion to PHP. Talking about all possible languages is not productive, since every one will be different.

Comment: @teelou there is a full answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/418162/4786273

Comment: @Random I think you mean the next one after that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2551988/476 – the answer you're pointing to only works for globals, which you're hopefully not dealing with most of the time.

Comment: @deceze the answer yes, but there are comments on it with attributes and local variables too. But the next answer is interesting too indeed

Comment: @teelou Note that you have exactly the same issue in your Javascript example with `var variable = undefined`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to test for a variable's existence in PHP; isset() is clearly broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418066/best-way-to-test-for-a-variables-existence-in-php-isset-is-clearly-broken)

Answer (score 5):

`isset` checks whether a variable [*is set **and not `null`***](http://php.net/isset). So yes, it will return `false` if the variable you're checking holds the value `null`. It is in fact impossible to distinguish a *non existent* variable from a variable holding `null`. People will suggest all sorts of hackarounds for this, but none of them work 100% of the time. In PHP you cannot distinguish these two cases, period.

Note that you can use more specialized methods to figure out the difference for [array keys](http://php.net/array_key_exists) or [object properties](http://php.net/property_exists), that's no problem. But plain variables are indistinguishable.

Having said that, you really shouldn't get into a situation where you need this distinction anyway. If you properly **initialize your variables**, you don't ever need to check whether they're *set*. *You* are in full control of all variables in your program, you *can* absolutely ensure that they exist when they should, so you don't need to check. If PHP then complains about non-existing variables, you know you have a bug which you can fix. All input that you *don't* control should come in the form of arrays or objects "from outside", which you can inspect in detail and distinguish `null` from non-existent keys.

See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: thanks. I found a way to get around it but not a elegant solution - i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get around it but it seems ugly,

```
$a = null;
$defined_vars = get_defined_vars();
var_dump(array_key_exists('a', $defined_vars)); // true
```

Comment: Note that this will fail for certain special cases, like `$_POST` inside a function scope. As I said, there is no 100% working workaround. You really need to ask yourself: why are you checking for the existence of a variable in the first place?! And the answer typically is: if you need to, you're doing it wrong and must initialise your variables properly instead.

Comment: You can just check is_null() because that will explicitly check for the „null“

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

> array_key_exists
>
> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.7, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8) array_key_exists — Checks if the
> given key or index exists in the array
>
> Description
>
> array_key_exists(string|int $key, array $array): bool
> array_key_exists() returns true if the given key is set in the array.
> key can be any value possible for an array index.